# When convert JSON with same name child elements but different types to XML using ConvertRecord in NiFi, some lines were lost

Tags: json, apache-nifi

I'd like to convert below flat json to xml using ConvertRecord processor in NiFi. The schema with component "Stream" that contains section with 3 items. The difference between them is that in one case child component "A" is object, in next one "A" is array, and in the third one "A" is object again, but they have the same name "C". My question is in the result, 2 lines were lost in the last "A":
"Description": "TYPE Q",
"Amount": "12"

The original input:

```
{"Stream":[{"C":{"A":{"Decode":"pay"}}},{"C":{"A":[{"Decode":"Tr","Amount":"12"},{"Decode":"To","Amount":"12"}]}},{"C":{"A":{"Decode":"Qualifications","Description":"TYPE Q","Amount":"12"}}}]}
```

The formatted input (put it here for easier view):

```
{
  "Stream": [
    {
      "C": {
        "A": {
          "Decode": "pay"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "C": {
        "A": [
          {
            "Decode": "Tr",
            "Amount": "12"
          },
          {
            "Decode": "To",
            "Amount": "12"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "C": {
        "A": {
          "Decode": "Qualifications",
          "Description": "TYPE Q",
          "Amount": "12"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The converted XML output from NiFi ConvertRecord (note that 2 lines under "Qualifications" were lost):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<temp>
   <Stream>
      <C>
         <A>
            <Decode>pay</Decode>
         </A>
      </C>
   </Stream>
   <Stream>
      <C>
         <A>
            <Decode>Tr</Decode>
            <Amount>12</Amount>
         </A>
         <A>
            <Decode>To</Decode>
            <Amount>12</Amount>
         </A>
      </C>
   </Stream>
   <Stream>
      <C>
         <A>
            <Decode>Qualifications</Decode>
         </A>
      </C>
   </Stream>
</temp>
```

My NiFi flowfile just includes one GenerateFlowFile and one ConvertRecord, as attached picture 1. The ConvertRecord processor uses a JsonTreeReader and a XmlRecordSetWriter controller service, as attached picture 2.

[The flowfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nm7M.png)

[The GenerateFlowFile configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQIR6.png)

[The JsonTreeReader configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISeW7.png)

[The XmlRecordSetWriter configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUg9X.png)

My question is, without changing original input, what should I do to fix the data lost? Is it any controller configuration that I need to change, or did I miss any processor that can do the validation? I feel like that it is the schema that are causing the problem. But don't know where to fix the schema.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `JsonTreeWriter` infers schema from first object it encountered and never alters afterwards. (naturally) if order is not important or able to be changed , below works otherwise you should use `avro` schema.  check this [sample](https://blogs.apache.org/nifi/entry/record-oriented-data-with-nifi) . of course your schema would be more complex

without explicit `avro` schema , you must provide all properties at first object like below. you may consider using json `null` for empty/null properties in your original json object

```json
    {
      "Stream": [
        {
          "C": {
            "A": {
              "Decode": "Qualifications",
              "Description": "TYPE Q",
              "Amount": "12"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "C": {
            "A": [
              {
                "Decode": "Tr",
                "Amount": "12"
              },
              {
                "Decode": "To",
                "Amount": "12"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "C": {
            "A": {
              "Decode": "pay"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

also note that you may need to `Suppress Null Values` on `XMLRecordSetWriter` in this solution

Comment: Hi yaprak, thanks a lot for your reply, it is very helpful! I planned to try your methods, but spent a lot of time creating the avro schema from my input json. So hard to translate the nested object + nested array json to avro schema. And not many online tools to do it... . Keep working it